# Learn CNN how background looks like & than extract foreground

Tags: image, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I have three types of images.

1. images that contains only background(white wall with black holes for cameras)
2. images that contains background + foreground(always person/part of body - depend on camera angle)
3. images that contains only manually extracted foreground

I want to automate process, so I don't need to manually extract foreground.

Problem is that background in 1st and 2nd image usually has different contrast, so I cannot just subtract them. On some images, background and foreground are almost the same color(person in white shirt - white shirt, white wall).

I've tried some CNN image segmentation projects, but none of them gave me a goodly enough results. Problem is, in my opinion, that they are using very small images as input, around 500x500. Mines are 3000x2000, so I need to resize them, and in that way I'm loosing accuracy. 
Also, all of CNNs are using only 2nd type images as input and 3rd type as output.

I have a few ideas in mind:

1. learn CNN how background looks like because on every images it's more or less the same, and then use that information for foreground extraction
2. feed the CNN with combined two images as input: 1st & 2nd and expected 3rd as output

I'm not sure how to do any of this, so any help is welcome. Also, new ideas are welcome as well. :)